# Customise the style of friendsPickerViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

Is there a way to customise the style of the `friendsPickerViewController` supplied with **facebook ios sdk 3.1**?

I am trying the change the look of the navigation bar in facebook's `friendsPickerViewController`.

Nothing seems to work. Not even the following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavBarBGImage"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it's a bit of a hack. First off, the `FBFriendPickerViewController` uses a `UIToolbar` instead of a `UINavigationBar`.

You have to present the `FBFriendPickerViewController`, then go through the subviews of its view to find the `UIToolbar` that's displayed at the top. Once you've found the `UIToolbar` you can modify it however you like.

So in the code for whichever view controller is going to display the friend picker, you could do it like:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *fbFriendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];

[fbFriendPickerController loadData];
[self presentViewController:fbFriendPickerController animated:NO completion:nil];

//Search through subviews of friendPicker until we find the UIToolbar
//NOTE: you have to do this after calling [self presentViewController...], otherwise
//the UIToolbar won't be in the array of subviews
NSArray *subs = [fbFriendPickerController.view subviews];
for (UIView *child in subs) {
    if ([child isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        UIToolbar *bar = (UIToolbar *)child;
        [bar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot customize the navigation bar's look. The customization is limited to features such as showing/hiding the done button and toolbar, plus filtering out friends to show in the picker.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize it, you have to create a new view controller which subclasses FBFriendPickerViewController, with a XIB file.

In your xib file, add a header view for ur navigation, a tableview and a spinner. Link the tableview and spinner to the file owner. And customize your header view as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any issues with all of the toolbars in your app being the same color, try: `[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];`

in your app delegate's *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method.

Thanks gwilkins for pointing out that it's a UIToolbar!